# android change tab icon

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to change tab icon when state changes. All is working properly if I use drawable from following xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/d_selected"
            android:state_selected="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/d_normal" />
</selector>
```

However, now I need to load images from data/data folder and drawables "d" and "dSel" are generated from these images. Using following code only "dSel" is shown and other tab images does not appear! Thank you

```
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed }, d);
                selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_selected }, dSel);
                selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_focused }, d);

          icon.setImageDrawable(selector);

    //icon.setImageResource(drawableId); used with other method described, if related to xml
```

Comment: try this `ImageView icon  = (ImageView) getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
icon .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.state_pressed));`

Comment: mmm and where are you assigning the image to state_press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. True/false for each state is handled by "-".

```
selector.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_selected }, dSel);
selector.addState(new int[]{ -android.R.attr.state_selected }, d);
```

refer to this link for more information, [Android : How to update the selector(StateListDrawable) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092649/android-how-to-update-the-selectorstatelistdrawable-programmatically)