# Whats the opposite of android.R.attr.state_checked?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a selector for button, with a state list drawable,

```
  states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked},
                               checkedDrawable.getDrawable());

    states.addState(new int[] {},
                               unCheckDrawable.getDrawable());
```

What should I put in second state ?
there is no android.R.attr.state_unchecked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092649/android-how-to-update-the-selectorstatelistdrawable-programmatically) might help you.

It says, that you should use the negative of the state you need. So in your case it should be:

```
states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, unCheckDrawable.getDrawable());
```