# Drawable.setState() How do I control the specific state of the drawable?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a drawable like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_pressed" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_selected" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_window_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_selected" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_normal" />
```

In code, how do I set my Drawable's specific state? I'd like to set it to the state_pressed=true state.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Got it. A comment from here helped: [Android : How to update the selector(StateListDrawable) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092649/android-how-to-update-the-selectorstatelistdrawable-programmatically)

So `Drawable.setState()` takes an array in integers. These integers represent the state of the drawable. You can pass any ints you want. Once the ints pass in match a an "item" from the state list drawables the drawable draws in that state.

It makes more sense in code:

```
int[] state = new int[] {android.R.attr.state_window_focused, android.R.attr.state_focused};
minThumb.setState(state);
```

Notice that my state list drawable has both the `state_pressed="true"` and `android:state_window_focused="true"`. So I have to pass both of those int values to `setState`. When I want to clear it, I just `minThumb.setState(new int[]{});`

Comment: What if the current view doesn't have a background, and need to notify its children about its state (because they have android:duplicateParentState="true" ) ? how would you change the state of the view ?

Comment: "It makes more sense in code" - nothing related to drawable states makes sense...

Comment: What is minThumb?

Answer (score 12):

Don't have enough points to comment, so this is just an addition to what android-developer said.  For certain states such as state_enabled, there is no obvious way to set the opposite value of that state (e.g. there is no state_disabled).  To indicate a negative or opposite state, simply pass the negative value of the resource for that state.

```
int[] state = new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}; //Essentially state_disabled
```

Then pass that integer array into the setState() method as usual.

```
minThumb.setState(state);
```

Comment: I did not test that but for me just not having `state_enabled` made it use the disabled color.