# Android set android:state_checked="false" in code

Tags: android

I want to create a selector using the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/sh_radio_icon_checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/sh_radio_icon_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

So far I have managed to add the first item, like this:

```
StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
int[] sFocusedSelected = {android.R.attr.state_checked};
Drawable dFocusedSelected = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sh_radio_icon_checked);
drawable.addState(sFocusedSelected, dFocusedSelected);
```

But do I add the state_checked=false since there's no state_unchecked constant?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable

Comment: @Tauqir I can't see how that is related to my question. Also everything there is solved in XML, I need to set it in code behind.

Answer (score 2):

Observe "-" (Minus/Hyphen) in the beginning of "android.R.attr.state_checked"

```
sld.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked  },  greyD);
```

[Android : How to update the selector(StateListDrawable) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092649/android-how-to-update-the-selectorstatelistdrawable-programmatically)