# Android ImageButton Pressed State Doesn't Change

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I am programatically setting the pressed state of an ImageButton.

Problem is when I press on it, the state does not change at all. I tried using `state_focused` and a few others but the button does not change at all. Do you know why my ImageButton is not changing its image when pressed?

```
    _pauseButton = new ImageButton(_context);

    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {},
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pausepressed));
    _pauseButton.setImageDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```

The default state image does show up correctly, but when its pressed, there is no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the default state LAST.

```
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pausepressed));
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {},
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
```

Looks like a bug in android and I've setup a report:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=217939&can=4&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
_pauseButton.setPressed(boolean)
```

If not help, try to read this article:
[Android : How to update the selector(StateListDrawable) programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092649/android-how-to-update-the-selectorstatelistdrawable-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks I'll try this when Im back in the office

Comment: Setting the pressed state does not work unfortunately