# How to set image on tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

Anyone please tell me how to set image on tab here is my code

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new HomeTab());
    tab.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_today));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: You can check this: 
[link1][1]

[link2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507718/
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5571787/1332870

Answer (score 0):

You can use setCustomView method.
Here is sample code.

```
    LinearLayout llt = new LinearLayout(this);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic_00_00_00);
    txt.setText("aaaaa");
    llt.addView(img);
    llt.addView(txt);
    tab.setCustomView(llt);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
tab.setIndicator("Tab Title",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myicon))
```

where R.drawable.myicon is the image or selector saved in project resources

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this code** :

tab.setIcon(**R.drawable.icon**);

And make sure that icon.png image exists in the drawable folder.