# Android - How do I change background image of a button when its pressed programmatically?

Tags: android, button

How do I do the following using Java instead of in xml?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/title_search_alt"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/title_search_alt"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: [Replace selector images programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks! I had searched for it the entire day without finding this!