# How to replace drawable source of a xml item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a drawable selector(home_button.xml) for a button, like...

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true"      
        android:drawable="@drawable/red_button" />
</selector>
```

And in my main activity's layout i'm using this drawable as

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/home_button" android:text="@string/home_button"
android:background="@drawable/home_button" ></Button>
```

Now i need to display dynamic remote images in place of local blue_button.png and red_button.png of selector xml inside activity based on the user login.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Android [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) class Documentation you get:

> If you're not satisfied with the default button style and want to
>   customize it to match the design of your application, then you can
>   replace the button's background image with a state list drawable.

You might want to replace the image button background drawable with an StateListDrawable you like in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically) post, assuming that you have downloading both images and have them as drawable objects already

```
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    //This for pressed true 
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
        drawable_image1);
    //This for pressed false
    states.addState(new int[] { },
        drawable_image2);
    //Change it on the button
    button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
```

Comment: thank you @Necronet, can you tell me how to set dynamic `LayerDrawable` that will be used as drawable for StateListDrawable state.

Comment: similar to what is done with StateListDrawable there is a class called [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) you can create an object and configured it on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html).

Comment: A little bit more of pation would have been nice!!

Answer (score 0):

If you create another drawable just set a new one in code:

```
public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)
```

Button is a View so this should work fine. [More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29).

If you need to change a 'Selector' take into account that a selector is just a 
[StateListDrawable.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) and so you could just create one programnatically adding the states as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Add your style

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```

and your selector (here btn_default.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
  </selector>
```

and your images (9 patch) btn_default_normal and btn_default_pressed (the names can be different than these) Then, apply the style to your button in xml:

```
<Button
      ...
      style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
   />
```