# How to set Android ImageButton backgroundimage for different states in Java Code

Tags: android, android-widget

I have defined a ImageButton as being drawn by a selector (which uses several images for different states). I need to change the way the buttons look during runtime.

I know I can use "setBackgroundResource" - but I have made the actual background resource a selector. I need to set the images for the specific states I have used in the selector.

So do I need to somehow obtain the selector, then set the images there? If I just call "setBackgroundResource" I assume this will negate the whole selector.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace selector images programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up simply replacing the selector when the button changes states as follows. Was fairly simple in the end. Inside the button's class:

```
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_normal));
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));

    this.setImageDrawable(states);
    this.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) you set, probably casting the `Drawable` returned by `getDrawable()` or `getBackground()` and then invoke [selectDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/DrawableContainer.html#selectDrawable%28int%29).

Comment: "selectDrawable" is undocumented. Assuming I get the StateListDrawable - I can't figure out how to set the images from there.

Comment: Use the numerical index of the drawable you want to select

Comment: So after I *select* the drawable, how do I *change* it?