# Is it possible to change "Up" icon to text (ActionBarSherlock)?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to change Action Bar "Up" icon to button (text + background image, like Back button on iOS), so I'll be able to change caption?

I know that I can use my own icon, but I need to change button caption programmaticaly.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically

Comment: @Tech.Rahul thanks, but by "programmaticaly" I meant something like `setText()` instead of redrawing icon :)

Comment: use ImageButton, then settext() in ur program..

Comment: sorry you cant do with imagebutton, you have to take Button b1, b1.setText("your text"); then create a style.xml make for button shape

Comment: @Tech.Rahul well, question is - how to replace icon in Action Bar with my button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29) 
and then `getActionBar().setCustomView(v);` where `View v` will be your button and custom title.
I think there is only this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check this out tommorow.

Comment: This is works (tested on ActionBarSherlock) as expected, thanks :) **BUT** you should call `getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)` before using custom view.