# Imitating Selector by code for ImageButton states in Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton`, where the source image is loaded dynamically from the network. My goal is to set different color filters on the image according to the button's state (i.e state_pressed, state_focused...). The problem is that I cant use `Selector` because my image is loaded dynamically and is not a drawable resource.
Does any one can give me a clue how can I recognize the state using code and imitate the selector's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the states programmatically as outlined by kcoppock in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697794/1309304)

```
Resources r = getResources();
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] {}, r.getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));

imageButton.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: And as you have dynamic images, instead if `r.getDrawable(...)` use `Drawable.createFromPath(pathName)`.

Comment: @antwe: It seems like a good start, but how do I set the color filter?  Calling 'setColorFilter' on the same drawable seem to have no effect.

Comment: @Ridcully: I forgot to thank you for your comment, it completed the answer. so - thank you :)