# How to set the state_pressed of a button

Tags: android, android-button

I use a xml file to color my button. In the xml a have this code to define the color of my button when it's clicked.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                  android:startColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundEnd"
                android:endColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart"

                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
           <shape>
            <gradient
                  android:startColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundEnd"
                android:endColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart"

                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart"
                android:endColor="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundEnd"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="@color/mainRaddoppiaButtonBackgroundStart" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Is it possibile from java to keep my button pressed and color it with "state_pressed" values set in my xml file?

Someting like:

```
  public void onClick(View button) {
     button.seLayout(R.xml.xmlFileName.state_pressed)
}
```

Of course this code has no sense, i just made it up to let you understand what i want to do

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Replace btn_pressed and btn_normal with respective drawable which you want.

Comment: button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xmlimage);

Answer (score 2):

use [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) for setting selector by code as:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));

 button.setBackgroundDrawable(states);//FOR BUTTON
```

Comment: mmm i did this: 
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.xml.XML_FILE_NAME_WHERE_I_DEFINED_THE_STATE_PRESSED)); but when i click the button, the button disappear

Comment: ok, sorry, i thought it was able to keep the color set in my xml file!
Thanl you

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali You need to add your selector file inside one of drawables. e.g **drawables/myselector.xml** --> `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myselector))`

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work. I miss something. I put the file with the code i wrote above (`<item android:state_pressed="true" >......`) in drawable folder and then i write  `states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.XML_FILE_NAME));` but the button still disappear when i click it.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali Did you added your `<item> inside <selector>`??

Comment: These SOQ is just duplicate of your question. You may found time worth visiting it --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable(){
    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
        //
    }
};
itemView.setBackground(states);
```