# Can't change item color in recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I can't change the color when the item is pressed
Here is my code
I have tried many ways but it doesn't seem to work

In the adapter,

```
binding.apply {
                barFilled.apply {
                    val color = context.getColor(R.color.selector_item_chart)
                    backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
                    var percentStepCounter: Float =
                        (item.stepCounter.toFloat() / ConstantNumber.MAX_STEP.toFloat())
                    if (percentStepCounter >= 1f) percentStepCounter = 1f
                    val params = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                    params.matchConstraintPercentHeight = percentStepCounter
                    requestLayout()
                }
                textSupporting.text = sdf.parse(item.date)?.let { newSimpleDateFormat.format(it) }
                textSupporting.setOnClickListener {
                    onClickControl.onClick(item)
                }
                barFilled.setOnClickListener {
                    onClickControl.onClick(item)
                }
            }
```

In item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="42sp"
    android:layout_height="212sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="4sp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingStart="10sp"
        android:paddingEnd="10sp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bar_filled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_chart_bar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_supporting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

và in selector_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/light_green" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_checkable="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_checkable="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/dark_green" android:state_window_focused="true" />

</selector>
```

with using select_item when it says to change color when clicked, and i tried all its properties but to no avail

I wish it would change the item color when I click on it

Comment: have you try to change it but just color without using your selector_item?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397282/how-to-set-the-state-pressed-of-a-button