# Add Color "#e3bb87" to StateListDrawable programmatically

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-selector

The reason I need to do this **programmatically** is that the text color is downloaded and not pre defined in the xml. I read this 
[Replace selector images programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)

I only need to know from

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
```

how turn into

```
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},**theMethodImLookingFor**("#e3bb87"));
```

forget about `getResources().getColor(R.color.anycolor)` , the color is not defined in xml

Comment: you can try using text.setTextColor( 0xff00ff00);

Comment: This is an interesting point. I would suggest to remove the explicit "#e3bb87" from the title, so people could easily find it for any color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#e3bb87")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [ColorDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html)

you can do something like this:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
int color = 0xff00ff00;
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
     new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Comment: thanks, I can only accept one answer. "There can only be one" like Highlander

Answer (score 0):

The method would be

```
new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#e3bb87"))
```