# Blue highlight over an ImageView when the user taps it

Tags: android, android-imageview, touch-feedback

I have a LinearLayout "card" with an ImageView and a TextView. I want the card to be highlighted when the user taps it. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx1l9Y7GIk8&feature=share&t=15m17s for an example.

This is easily done for the TextView by setting `android:background="@drawable/blue_highlight"`. Below is res/drawable/blue_highlight.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/selected"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/bg_window"/>
</selector>
```

But this does not work for the ImageView because the image is in front and the background is not visible. How can I have the touch highlight effect with a semi-transparent color for an ImageView?

Comment: I believe you can put your LinearLayout into FrameLayout and set foreground attribute for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazingly, FrameLayout has the [foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android:foreground) attribute which can be used for this. The disadvantage is that you have to add an extra FrameLayout element. The implementation is simple, so until you have time to implement fancy image processing (de-colorize the image a bit, then apply the highlight) and building state drawables dynamically, this seems good enough.

So in my case this would be:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:foreground="@drawable/blue_highlight_image"
    >
  <ImageView ...>
</FrameLayout>
```

@drawable/blue_highlight_image uses a new @color/pressed_image value which is similar with @color/pressed but has an alpha channel, for example: #81CFEB -> #AA81CFEB.

Thanks @Vang for the suggestion.

Comment: For the default blue color, you can use this: `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: This works great, and as @aleb mentioned it, I used alpha 30% to make it look like highlight (30% alpha = 4D in hex).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way. Try to use the blue_highlight.xml as your drawable but instead using colors in there use the image you want to show and define a second drawable that adds a color filter to the image when highlighted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable_with_colorfilter"/>
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/yourdrawable_with_colorfilter"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks. Might work great for static images. More difficult to implement if the images are from a database or downloaded.

Comment: You are right. But you did not mention this. For being more dynamic you can programm the selector. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically) you can find a good example (the accepted answer).