# Set textview focus color programmatically / change focus color in themes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

**1) Is it possible to set a TextView's color programmatically? If so what's the easiest way?**

I want something else other that the default 4.0+ light-blue color.

I found and tried the following code without success:

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(0x1A000000));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(0x1A000000));

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    tv.setBackgroundDrawable(states);
} else {
    tv.setBackground(states);
}
```

I do not wish any XML involved.

**2) Can I change the focus color in my themes in general? If yes how?**

XML is obviously fine here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), to specify the state color programmatically.

```
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}, // pressed
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, // focused
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled} // enabled
    };

    int[] colors = new int[] {
        Color.parseColor("#008000"), // Green
        Color.parseColor("#0000FF"), // Blue
        Color.parseColor("#FF0000")  // Red
    };
    
    ColorStateList list = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    textView.setTextColor(list);        
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: You are correct, this is the solution to the question. Although I wrote a wrong question (I wanted background color instead of text color). Here's the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Create file res/drawable/text_color.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

Then use `@drawable/text_color` from xml (or `R.drawable.text_color` from code) as text color for your TextView.

Comment: in this case please use `setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.text_color));`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to set color if some event happents? If it is then you can set textView color as follow:

```
  textView.setTextColor("give color-code");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create style for that.
By using style you can modify text color, background color, etc whatever you want.

Comment: Create custom style then set that style to the application in manifest file

Comment: Hmm tried `<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">#1000</item>` without success.

Comment: look at this one [SetListDrawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)
it has a very alike situation, and a specific answer.