# Radio Button is only partially checked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I know this sound weird so here is the picture.

[image]

It hold the correct value. The correct radiobutton is (partially) selected. All logic in the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is executed correctly. I'm completly stunned. Why is the radio button not fully checked?

Only thing I can think of is that i'm using `Rx2Firebase`

```
periodRetriever = FirebaseHelper.getInstance(getContext()).getPeriod()
        .defaultIfEmpty(0)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(@NonNull Integer headerType) throws Exception {
                getRadioViewChecked(headerType).setChecked(true);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT1**

Marcos suggestion I can't see the white tick. This is not the case.
[image]

**EDIT2**

Layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgPeriod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMonth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/month" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbWeek"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/week" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb4Weeks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/four_weeks" />


</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that the circle does not have the dot in the center? If so, what is your theme, and have you done anything to customize the look of the `RadioButton`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that is what i'm referring to! I haven't done anything with the styling apart from setting `colorPrimary` and `colorAccent`. I did not have this problem when it was all synchronous.

Comment: Maybe the theme you extends from uses white selection dots
If you using Dark theme switch to Light, or inverse otherwise

Comment: When I select it manually it works normal. Also when the event triggers for the second time.

Comment: Did you try to handle it on main thread with `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(...)`?

Comment: @g4s8 Unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Add your xml layout

Comment: Are you setting the drawable for the radiobutton dynamically?

Comment: @PabloBaxter only the color

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like an Animation Bug. When using a CompoundButton on a Fragment inside a ViewPager the drawable state is not set correctly.

This happens also for Checkboxes as seen here: [Android Nougat: Why do checkboxes on Fragment have incomplete state when selected programmatically (but look fine on Lollipop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516506/android-nougat-why-do-checkboxes-on-fragment-have-incomplete-state-when-selecte).

Calling jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() just after calling RadioGroup.check(id) or Checkbox.setChecked(true) seems to fix the problem (thx @Dalmas)

Comment: After all these answers finally something that makes sense.

Comment: This is happening on a Nexus 5x API 27. The fragment is within an activity with a fragment adapter. #jumpDrawablesToCurrentState fixed it

Comment: For me jumpDrawablesToCurrentState fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: radioButton.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(); is worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answer of @Nipper, I wrote a Kotlin extension in my project to easily fix the issue :

```
fun CompoundButton.setCheckedFixed(checked: Boolean) {
    isChecked = checked
    jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
}
```

Everywhere I should do `radioButton.isChecked = true` or `radioButton.setChecked(true)` instead I do `radioButton.setCheckedFixed(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is Dark and you cant see the white tick, you need to change it to another color.

Comment: Obs: I did commented this on Aug28

Comment: If that's true, changing the background colour of my activty would reveal this right? But then comes a new question to my mind, why is it sometimes white and sometimes not?

Comment: It is dependent of the device you are testing with, and yes, chaning the background would make it appear

Comment: Then why is it sometimes white and sometimes not? Same device though

Comment: Hmm, maybe its a animation issue? Are you sure your method is checking only one of yours checks?

Comment: Absolutly sure.

Comment: So create a minimum reproducible code so we can test

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your **Theme** or the color attributes of your radio button

Answer (score -1):

change background color from white to another color it will appear

Comment: How did you miss that red picture?

Comment: sorry Robin  Dijkhof  sir

Comment: i think he is applying some theme

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `RadioButton` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` i think that might solve the issue

On the other hand, here you can find a doc of how to style RadioButtons

http://www.materialdoc.com/radio-button/

1. Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

`<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>`

2. Apply this style to your RadioButton via android:theme attribute.

`

```
   <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Radio Button"
        android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton"/>
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044856/4492504