# Radio Button is partially unchecked on Oreo

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-radiobutton, android-8.1-oreo

I am getting strange behavior of Radio Button in `Oreo 8.0.1`, Radio button is partially selected which is already discussed on `Stackoverflow` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926301/radio-button-is-only-partially-checked?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516506/android-nougat-why-do-checkboxes-on-fragment-have-incomplete-state-when-selecte). [image]
In above Image `First Radio Button` is partially selected, this occurs only when we checked radio button `programmatically` This is I think animation bug according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531596/3026578) and fixed with calling `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` , but now I am getting `partially unChecked` when changing the state only `programmatically` first time, please look [image] 
Here First Radio Button is selected but second radio button is still partially checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it looks like an animation bug, but you should refresh your layout using invalidate and requestLayout methods

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    view.invalidate();
    view.requestLayout();
 }
```

Comment: I think `requestLayout` adds unnecessary performance cost since layout didn't change. Why don't you explain what each method does and why should we call it?

Comment: @Eugen Pechane thanks, Is there any best solution to avoid such kind of issues, As I am getting this only in `Oreo 8.0.1`  but this one solving my issue.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec i also came across the same issue on Oreo device only and these line of code help me fix that, if you have any better solution do let me know

Comment: My guess is that `invalidate` would suffice. `invalidate` forces redraw, which should be enough because only alpha is broken. `requestLayout` forces recomputing position of the whole layout hierarchy, which is waste of CPU because the position is correct. I want you to know what you're doing. In your answers explain what your code does so other people know it as well. @HussainSherwani Don't just blindly copy-paste something without understanding.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Thanks for this, actually I am not blindly copy pasting the code, I tried this with `invalidate` only but still I was facing issue, kindly check ..`https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281876/3026578` also I already fixed this issue before this answer... Cheers

Comment: @HussainSherwani Thanks for that link, yes, I was expecting something like that in this answer too. The link says: `If you are not doing anything to your view that would change its size, then you do not have to call requestLayout().` so now the question is, why your case doesn't work without `requestLayout`...

Comment: Thanks, Actually my `Radio Button` is not in `RadioGroup`, I was handling them manually, in some situation I show `three button` in some condition I show `two` and `one` too according to my situation.  Actually this is animation bug it occurred in a specific scenario only first time, second time when I repeat same scenario this will not occur,  I `debugged` this too. In debugging I got `mCheked  = false` for second button. but it show as partially check . look like animation bug. Cheers