# How change Switch state only if some condition is true?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, conditional-statements, uiswitch

I want that my Switch change to checked if some condition is true, else, show a toast informing the user what happen. I'm trying:

```
switch?.setOnclickListener{
if(condition)   switch!!.isChecked=true
else
//Show toast
}
```

But i know that condition is false and the switch change to checked. How to do the change of switch only when some condition is true?

Comment: This should work. You should check that you are appropriately calculating the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
    var condition = true
    if (condition == true) {
        switch.isChecked = true
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is a toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Its also possible that your switch is checked by default, your xml should look something like this:

```
    <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="Switch" />
```

If one of the tags is `android:checked="true"`, set it to `false`.

Comment: Why does this not work for you? Try to set your condition to `condition = false` directly in front of your `if` clause, if it still gets checked, some other code in your project is the reason, else your condition was just wrong. @mojojojo

Comment: UPDATE!. Work fine

Answer (score 0):

Everything seemed to be working for me.

but I found in a different Question that had a similar problem, that they used

```
checkBox.setChecked(true)
checkbox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()
```

and it worked for them. does any of it help?

here is the original link:
[Why CheckBox checked not working with Kotlin programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520466/why-checkbox-checked-not-working-with-kotlin-programmatically)