# Android state list programmatically

Tags: android, list, drawable, state

I have an State List, which I assign to elements in my List view.

Here is a Selector:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#1E90FF"/>
      <stroke android:width="2dp"
          android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
    </item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
      <stroke android:width="2dp"
          android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
```

I need to realize, that user may choose a color for elements without losses stroke and accentuation `state_pressed="true"`.

How I can programmatically change the color in my state list?

Comment: I think this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4697794/3864698