# android: how to create a drawable with normal/pressed states programmably

Tags: android, drawable

It is simple to specify the view background drawable with normal/pressed states in the .xml, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="false"  
        android:color="@color/setting_color_select" />  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/setting_color_select" />  

</selector>
```

But how to create a drawable programmably with the focus or pressed state specified? I didn't find the answer in the developer docs.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically) answer

Answer (score 0):

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
         getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
         getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },
         getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: Copy & Paste [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697528/replace-selector-images-programmatically)